# How to find the values of a parent node in a Huffman tree using Python

Tags: python, heapq

I did not write this code.  I am trying to draw a Huffman Tree out of this but I want the values of the parent nodes and put them in a list with its binary code.  How can I achieve this?

```
import heapq
from collections import defaultdict


def encode(frequency):
    heap = [[weight, [symbol, '']] for symbol, weight in frequency.items()]
    heapq.heapify(heap)
    while len(heap) > 1:
        lo = heapq.heappop(heap)
        hi = heapq.heappop(heap)
        for pair in lo[1:]:
            pair[1] = '0' + pair[1]
        for pair in hi[1:]:
            pair[1] = '1' + pair[1]
        heapq.heappush(heap, [lo[0] + hi[0]] + lo[1:] + hi[1:])
    return sorted(heapq.heappop(heap)[1:], key=lambda p: (len(p[-1]), p))


data="ALL PEOPLE SEEM TO NEED DATA PROCESSING."

frequency = defaultdict(int)
for symbol in data:
    frequency[symbol] += 1

huff = encode(frequency)
print ("Symbol".ljust(10) + "Weight".ljust(10) + "Huffman Code")
for p in huff:
    print(p[0].ljust(10) + str(frequency[p[0]]).ljust(10) + p[1])
```

Link to image of Huffman tree using Turtle: https://imgur.com/a/Ql0QIDD

Comment: I have figured out how to solve this.  I uploaded the full version on my github: https://github.com/HughJazz123/Python---Huffman-tree-drawer

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a complete huffman coder from this that includes the binary of the encode:

You can see a tree by uncommenting the print, but if there is something more your looking for, let me know.

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop, heapify
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce

def encode(symb2freq):
    heap = [[wt, [sym, ""]] for sym, wt in symb2freq.items()]
    heapify(heap)
    while len(heap) > 1:
        lo = heappop(heap)
        hi = heappop(heap)
        for pair in lo[1:]:
            pair[1] = '0' + pair[1]
        for pair in hi[1:]:
            pair[1] = '1' + pair[1]
        heappush(heap, [lo[0] + hi[0]] + lo[1:] + hi[1:])
    return dict(sorted(heappop(heap)[1:], key=lambda p: (p, len(p[-1]))))

# recreates the original message from your huffman code table 
# uncomment print(a) to see how it works
def decompressHuffmanCode(a, bit):
    # print(a)
    return ('', a[1] + s[a[0]+bit[0]]) if (a[0]+bit[0] in s) else (a[0]+bit[0], a[1])

data="ALL PEOPLE SEEM TO NEED DATA PROCESSING."

# Create symbol to frequency table
symb2freq = defaultdict(int)
for ch in data:
    symb2freq[ch] += 1
enstr=encode(symb2freq)

# Create Huffman code table from frequency table
s=dict((v,k) for k,v in dict(enstr).items())

# Create compressible binary. We add 1 to the front, and remove it when read from disk
compressed_binary = '1' + ''.join([enstr[item] for item in data])

# Read compressible binary so we can uncompress it. We strip the first bit.
read_compressed_binary = compressed_binary[1:]

# Recreate the compressed message from read_compressed_binary
remainder,bytestr = reduce(decompressHuffmanCode, read_compressed_binary, ('', ''))
print(bytestr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I am trying to draw the Huffman tree using Turtle. Link to the example given:  https://imgur.com/a/Ql0QIDD

Comment: Ok ill take a look at that for this